# XSLT Count elements with specific text nodes

Tags: xslt

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PetShop>
    <Cage>
        <Occupant1>Parrot</Occupant1>
        <Occupant2>Parrot</Occupant2>
    </Cage>
    <Cage>
        <Occupant1>Monkey</Occupant1>
        <Occupant2>Parrot</Occupant2>
    </Cage>
    <Cage>
        <Occupant1>Parrot</Occupant1>
        <Occupant2>Parrot</Occupant2>
    </Cage>
    <Cage>
        <Occupant1>Parrot</Occupant1>
        <Occupant2>Monkey</Occupant2>
    </Cage>
</PetShop>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PetShop">
    <ul>
        <li>Occupant 1 Parrots: <xsl:value-of select="count(//Cage/Occupant1[text() = 'Parrot'])"/></li>
        <li>Occupant 2 Monkeys: <xsl:value-of select="count(//Cage/Occupant2[text() = 'Monkey'])"/></li>
        <li>Occupant 1 Parrots with Occupant 2 Monkeys: <xsl:value-of select="count(//Cage/Occupant1[text() = 'Parrot'] and /Occupant2[text()='Monkey'])" /></li>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

My Problem is this: I want  to get the number of cages where Occupant1 is 'Parrot' and Occupant2 is 'Monkey' using the stylesheet above. This is a similar problem to another post ([Count xml elements with multiple conditions and precise properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677496/count-xml-elements-with-multiple-conditions-and-precise-properties#)) where Lingamurthy CS's solution was:

```
count(home/place[property[@Name='Type' and @Value='house'] and property[@Name='Context' and @Value='kitchen']])
```

However, I cannot get this to work for my text nodes. Really appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the number of cages where Occupant1 is Parrot and Occupant2 is Monkey.

```
count(/PetShop/Cage[Occupant1 = 'Parrot' and Occupant2 = 'Monkey'])
```

In the context PetShop, simply:

```
count(Cage[Occupant1 = 'Parrot' and Occupant2 = 'Monkey'])
```